# I need to write a function that will reverse the spelling of every word in a string (python) but Idk where im going wrong

Tags: python

explanation:

> Given a sentence `<s>`, we define a word within  to be a continuous sequence of characters in `<s>` that starts with a capital letter and ends before the next capital letter in the string or at the end of the string, whichever comes first. A word can include a mixture of punctuation and spaces.

```
def reverse_sentence(s: string) -> string:
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[s[i].isupper() + i].islower():
            rev_word = rev_word + s[::-1]

        if s[i].isupper():
            rev_word = rev_word + s[i]

    return rev_word
```

```
# doc strings
# >>> reverse_sentence('ATest string!')
#    'A!gnirts tseT'

#  >>> reverse_sentence('Peer Rep')
#    'reeP peR'

#  >>> reverse_sentence('Amazing')
#   'gnizamA'
```

I basically got the following results

```
reverse_sentence('ATest string!')

Expected:'A!gnirts tseT'
Got:'A!gnirts tseTAT!gnirts tseTA!gnirts tseTA!gnirts tseTA!gnirts tseTA!gnirts tseTA!gnirts tseTA!gnirts tseTA!gnirts tseTA!gnirts tseTA'

reverse_sentence('Peer Rep')

Expected:'reeP peR'
Got:'peR reePPpeR reePpeR reePpeR reePpeR reePRpeR reePpeR reeP'

reverse_sentence('Amazing')

Expected:'gnizamA'
Got:'gnizamAAgnizamAgnizamAgnizamAgnizamAgnizamAgnizamA'
```

I've tried a different approach where I would do nested if functions with variable like `index_word = 0` and `rev_word = ""` so that I could reverse each word one by one and store it into an empty string but i kept getting `""` as an outcome

PS: i'm not allowed to use list/list functions or add any imports

Comment: Can you explain why you wrote the code you're showing? E.g. can you explain the procedure that you wanted to implement, in words and steps, and then relate that to the code you wrote?

Comment: Did you get this code from an AI?

Comment: Given a sentence <s>, we define a word within <s> to be a continuous
    sequence of characters in <s> that starts with a capital letter and
    ends before the next capital letter in the string or at the end of
    the string, whichever comes first. A word can include a mixture of
    punctuation and spaces.    im stuck on how i can fix this code so that the outcome doesnt repeat

Comment: Put that explanation in the question, not a comment.

Comment: i did not get this from AI, this is how my TA kind of "lead me"

Comment: what does "im not allowed to use "list/list functions" mean exactly?  what does "a word can contain spaces imply?" I dont know of any words that include spaces

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think it means they're not allowed to first convert the input string to a list of words, then loop over that.

Comment: @Barmar yes! thats what i meant, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Barmar (yeah i figured i would ask because of your split comment (gone now;P)... )not sure what a word with spaces is though yet...)

Comment: This code shouldn't even run, it should get an error that `rev_word` hasn't been set before being used.

Comment: @JoranBeasley The instructions make it clear that words are defined by an initial uppercase letter, not whitespace or punctuation.

Comment: @JoranBeasley basically if a word is spelt like "Ele ph ant" or a string like "Over Rainbow"

Comment: `s[s[i].isupper() + i]` makes no sense. Why are you adding `i` to the True/False result of `isupper()`?

Comment: then the word includes spaces ... so basically just `"tna hp elE"`  .. which is to say just `whole_sentence[::-1]` ? I feel like we need more test cases

Comment: @Barmar i wanted to to see if the letter after an uppercase was lower case but in terms of how i can achieve that.. i really don't know, i've only started learning recently

Comment: @JoranBeasley yeah like that, but im having trouble when a string is like " Over Rainbow" bc the outcome is supposed to be "revO wobniaR"

Comment: If you want to test the next letter, you should be using `s[i+1].islower()`, but that will get an error when `i` is the last letter.

Comment: @Barmar i've tried that as well however i would get a result of  "  " and thats all :(

Comment: @A_duckycake Peer Rep would become " reePpeR" since the space would be part of peer?  why would it be "reeP peR" like in your doctest assertion?

Comment: @JoranBeasley My TA said the spaces should be kept the same?  because were only reversing the word.... i also do not understand..... but i think you are correct it doesn't make sense

Comment: that starts with a capital letter and ends before the next capital letter in the string or at the end of the string, whichever comes first. A word can include a mixture of punctuation and spaces. ... per your own definition the space should be part of the word `"Peer "`

Comment: Thank you guys so much for helping me I really appreciate it, this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow, thank you for your patience @JoranBeasley&@barmar and to anyone else that helped out :)

Answer (score 0):

you should split your problem into two parts the first to find all "words" (in this case words are delimitted by Capital letters not by spaces)

```
def find_words(s):
    s1 = ""
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper() and s1:
            # here you can do some extra checks 
            # ie if s1 endswith a space 
            #        then remove the space and yield it seperately

            yield s1
            s1 = ""
        s1 += c
    if s1:
        yield s1
```

you can then write some tests for this

```
print(list(find_words("ATest string!")))
```

then you just need to reverse each string

```
def reverse_strings(s):
    for word in find_words(s):
        yield word[::-1]

print("".join(reverse_strings("ATest string!")))
```

here is an alternative version of find words that would treat a single space at the end of s1 as its own "word" effectively preserving the space in "Peer Rep" (but it would not necessarily cover the case of multiple spaces)

```
def find_words(s):
    s1 = ""
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper() and s1:
            if(s1.endswith(" ")):
                yield s1[:-1]
                yield " "
            else:
                yield s1
            s1 = ""
        s1 += c
    if s1:
        yield s1
```

Comment: My prof said we cannot use any imports and need to utilise string indices, however I can understand this way a little better so thank you

Comment: wait so that is much more restrictive than your addendum "PS I cannot use lists"

Comment: I tried this and got a <generator object reverse_sentence at 0x000001CA2A65B0D0> T_T

Comment: you need to "".join or do something to cause the generator to evaluate... if you copy the the calls with the "".join you will see it evaluates :)

Answer (score 0):

When a capital letter is encountered, append the sub-string.

```py
def f(x):
    s = ''
    a = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(x):
        if i != a and c.isupper():
            s += x[a:i][::-1]
            a = i
    s += x[a:][::-1]
    return s
```

Output

```
A!gnirts tseT
 reePpeR
gnizamA
```

Answer (score -1):

This reproduces the desired results without lists. Feel free to improve.

```
def reverse_sentence(s):
    words = ""
    cur_word = ""
    def rev_word(word):
        # Reverse - with trailing spaces removed
        rev = word.rstrip()[::-1]
        # Put trailing spaces back in at the end
        for c in word[::-1]:
            if c == ' ': rev += ' '
            else: break;
        return rev
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper():
            words += rev_word(cur_word)
            cur_word = ""
        cur_word += c
    words += rev_word(cur_word)
    return words.strip()
```

```
>>> reverse_sentence('ATest string!')
'A!gnirts tseT'
>>> reverse_sentence('Peer Rep')
'reeP peR'
>>> reverse_sentence('Amazing')
'gnizamA'
>>> reverse_sentence(' Over Rainbow')
'revO wobniaR'
```